# How EC2 instances don't require password for sudo for Ubuntu user but 'include' is commented?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

There is a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` that makes the Ubuntu user passwordless for sudo.

However, in `/etc/sudoers` the 'include' line is commented.

How then is that config loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is not commented - it's a [C-style include directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive#C.2FC.2B.2B). From `man sudoers`:

> **Including other files from within sudoers**
>
> It is possible to include
>    other sudoers files from within the sudoers   file currently being
>    parsed using the `#include` and `#includedir` directives.